# I am using the try in PHP but the PDO wont catch the exception

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hey for some reason i will use the try keyword in php to catch the PDO exception but it wont. I would put random incorrect details and it shows PDO Uncaught Exception and it show the connection details. It works i can execute the sql statements but when the conn details are incorrect it says uncaught PDO exception. This is for a framework i am working on.

the global file calls all the other files but il only include the database classes because thats where the problem is.

`Global.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Framework;
define('APP_VERSION', '1.0.0');
defined("START") ? null : define("START", microtime());
define('DEBUG', true);
if (DEBUG) {
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
} else {
  error_reporting(0);
  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
}
include_once 'LinkConfig.php';
include_once 'LinkInterface.php';
include_once 'Link.php';
try {
  $Link = new Link(
    LinkConfig::DRIVER,
    LinkConfig::HOST,
    LinkConfig::DBNAME,
    LinkConfig::USER,
    LinkConfig::PASS,
    LinkConfig::CHARSET,
    LinkConfig::PORT
  );
} catch (PDOException $Exception) {
  die('Connection failed: ' . $Exception->getMessage());
}


?>
```

This is the DB connection interface file

`LinkInterface.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Framework;
defined('START') || (header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden') & die('403.14 - Directory listing denied.'));
interface ILink {
  public function __construct($Driver, $Host, $DBName, $User, $Pass, $Charset, $Port);
  public function Select($Sql, $Array = array(), $FetchMode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  public function Insert($Table, array $Data);
  public function Update($Table, $Data, $Where, $WhereBindArray = array());
  public function Delete($Table, $Where, $Bind = array(), $Limit = null);
}

?>
```

This is the DB connection config file.

`LinkConfig.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Framework;
defined('START') || (header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden') & die('403.14 - Directory listing denied.'));
class LinkConfig {
  const DRIVER = 'mysql';
  const HOST = 'localhost';
  const DBNAME = 'test';
  const USER = 'root';
  const PASS = '';
  const CHARSET = 'utf8';
  const PORT = '3306';
  const DEBUG = true;
}

?>
```

And the last file is where it all happens.

`Link.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Framework;
defined('START') || (header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden') & die('403.14 - Directory listing denied.'));
use \PDO;
class Link extends PDO {
  public function __construct($Driver, $Host, $DBName, $User, $Pass, $Charset, $Port) {
    parent::__construct($Driver . ':host=' . $Host . ';port=' . $Port . ';dbname=' . $DBName . ';charset=' . $Charset, $User, $Pass);
    $this->exec('SET CHARACTER SET ' . $Charset);
    if (LinkConfig::DEBUG) {
      $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    }
  }
  public function Select($Sql, $Array = array(), $FetchMode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    $Sth = $this->prepare($Sql);
    foreach ($Array as $Key => $Value) {
      $Sth->bindValue(":$Key", $Value);
    }
    $Sth->execute();
    return $Sth->fetchAll($FetchMode);
  }
  public function Insert($Table, array $Data) {
    ksort($Data);
    $FieldNames = implode('`, `', array_keys($Data));
    $FieldValues = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($Data));
    $Sth = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO $Table (`$FieldNames`) VALUES ($FieldValues)");
    foreach ($Data as $Key => $Value) {
      $Sth->bindValue(":$Key", $Value);
    }
    $Sth->execute();
  }
  public function Update($Table, $Data, $Where, $WhereBindArray = array()) {
    ksort($Data);
    $FieldDetails = null;
    foreach ($data as $Key => $Value) {
      $FieldDetails .= "`$Key`=:$Key,";
    }
    $FieldDetails = rtrim($FieldDetails, ',');
    $Sth = $this->prepare("UPDATE $Table SET $FieldDetails WHERE $Where");
    foreach ($Data as $Key => $Value) {
      $Sth->bindValue(":$Key", $Value);
    }
    foreach ($WhereBindArray as $Key => $Value) {
      $Sth->bindValue(":$Key", $Value);
    }
    $Sth->execute();
  }
  public function Delete($Table, $Where, $Bind = array(), $Limit = null) {
    $Query = "DELETE FROM $Table WHERE $Where";
    if ($Limit) {
      $Query .= " LIMIT $Limit";
    }
    $Sth = $this->prepare($Query);
    foreach ($Bind as $Key => $Value) {
      $Sth->bindValue(":$Key", $Value);
    }
    $Sth->execute();
  }
}

?>
```

Is there a logical explaination why it is showing uncaught PDO exception.

This is the error message i get.

this is what it outputs `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\Link.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\Link.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\Global.php(33): App\Framework\Link->__construct('mysql', 'localhostz', 'test', 'root', '', 'utf8', '3306') #2 {main} Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\Link.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\Link.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\Global.php(33): App\Framework\Link->__construct('mysql', 'localhostz', 'test', 'root', '', 'utf8', '3306') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\Link.php on line 8`

Comment: you're calling `die` inside `catch`, I'm not expert in php but I think that will throw an exception right ?

Comment: anyway could you show us the stacktrace ? specifically at what file of the above and at what line

Comment: It should be okay to call die in a catch. Echo does nothing still says PDO uncaught exception

Comment: die still executes if the pdo exception is caught

Comment: and stacktrace?

Comment: yes the stacktrace would be helpful, and yes calling `die` inside catch is ok I think :)

Comment: don't mind me asking what is a stacktrace thats new lol

Comment: at least for me

Comment: stacktrace is call stack from the line where the exception was thrown to the method the exception which threw it to the method that called to the method that called the method that called to ...., php should show it to you when you see `Uncaught Exception`

Comment: so for example if `f1` called `f2` and `f2` called `f3` and `f3` threw `Exception` the stack trace would be `Exception e : Message \n at f1(line number,col number)\n at f2(line number,col number)\n at f3(line number,col number)`

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment because I am not sure if this is what you need but try assigning an error handler function with `set_error_handler`and `E_WARNING` as the second parameter.

Comment: i would have put it as a commnet but it was long

Comment: AH HA FIGURED IT OUT

Comment: Thanks guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out it was the use of the namespaces by changing `Global.php` to:

```
<?php
use App\Framework as Framework;
define('APP_VERSION', '1.0.0');
defined("START") ? null : define("START", microtime());
define('DEBUG', true);
if (DEBUG) {
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
} else {
  error_reporting(0);
  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
}
include_once 'LinkConfig.php';
include_once 'LinkInterface.php';
include_once 'Link.php';
try {
  $Link = new Framework\Link(
    Framework\LinkConfig::DRIVER,
    Framework\LinkConfig::HOST,
    Framework\LinkConfig::DBNAME,
    Framework\LinkConfig::USER,
    Framework\LinkConfig::PASS,
    Framework\LinkConfig::CHARSET,
    Framework\LinkConfig::PORT
  );
} catch (PDOException $Exception) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $Exception->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: "Because when you are catching the exception can have no namespaces active." Sure you can, you just have to do `catch (\PDOException $Exception)` instead. The `\\` tells it to start at the top-level namespace.

Comment: trying to get use to namespaces so i am using them a lot the more i use them the more i get better with them